# mysql showing only zeros when I post on my website

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am creating a PHP website and I want to insert comments. When the comments are posted I want to show the current date but I only get this: 0000-00-00 00:00:00
I had type datetime, default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, but it doesn't work. I took it off, same thing. i just have type datetime on mysql db.

PHP code:

```
 <?php

       include ('db_connect2.php');
       require ('header.php');
       require ('login.php');
       include ('comments.php');
       date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');




<?php
   echo "<form method='POST' action='".setComments($conn)."'>
         <input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='Anonymous'>
         <input type='hidden' name='posted' value='".date('YYYY-MM-DD 
         HH:MM:SS')."'>
        <textarea name='body'></textarea><br><br>
        <button name='commentSubmit' type='submit'>Comment</button>
        </form>";
?>
```

comments.php

```
setComments($conn);
   function setComments($conn) {
      if (isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])){
        $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
        $posted = $_POST['posted'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (user_id, posted, body) VALUES 
        ('$user_id', '$posted', '$body')";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  }

 }

      function getComments($conn) {
              $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
              $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
              while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
              echo "<div class='comment-box'><p>";
              echo $row['user_id']."<br>";
              echo $row['posted']."<br>";
              echo nl2br($row['body']);
             echo "</p></div>";



    }
 }
```

Comment: About this part *"and I want to insert comments"* - I don't see an INSERT.

Comment: That is on my comments.php document. Comments are being posted, current time is just not showing.

Comment: Without your `comments.php` this isn't answerable

Comment: ok i added it.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong format for your [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in the hidden input being:

```
date('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')
```

That should have echo'd back something like this:

> 2018201820182018-OctOct-TueTue 2323:OctOct:thth

What you want is to use the same format that [MySQL uses](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date), but in a PHP format:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

Which would have echo'd out something like this:

> 2018-10-30 23:01:23

**Tip:** Always look at your HTML source, it's also a "tool".

**Caution**: Your code is open to SQL injection. Please use a prepared statement for this.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Comment: @Paola Please reload my answer. I added an important note about SQL injection. Stay safe.

Comment: =} cheers. i can finally go to sleep. I was googling for mysql date errors and did not think to check on my PHP date format. Thanks again!!!